# PHP not assigning variable

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending information to a php file through a AJAX post mat hod and the PHP can echo the data but will not assign it to a variable and I can not seem to understand why. The first echo works but the second echo only seems to get the hours. The AJAX in not encoded.

I just learned PHP a few weeks ago so I expect this problem to be very simple to fix.

Thank you

```
<?php
    echo ($_POST['userName']);
    $usernam = ($_POST['userName']);
    $eventid = ($_POST['eventid']);
    $hours = ($_POST["hours"]);
    echo $eventid+$usernam+$hours+"<br><br><br>";
?>
```

Comment: You don't need parentheses around those variables.

Comment: Variable and string Concatenation in php is . not +

Comment: @Popnoodles is there a rule as to when use quotes?

Comment: Quotes? Strings inside double-quotes `"` are parsed, strings inside single quotes `'` are not. So `echo "$a";` gives the value of a, the same as `echo $a;` but `echo '$a';` gives the literal string `$a` not its value. Parentheses `(` `)` like in math are used to force precedence (isolate a calculation/condition), e.g. `($a - $b) * $c` may not equal `$a - $b * $c` and `if (($a  || $b) && $c)` may not equal `if ($a || $b && $c)`

Comment: @Popnoodles Ok thanks. In the $_POST[] do I need quotes in there? I have seen it work with and without the quotes so I was wondering if there was a reason to use them.

Comment: Yes you need them. You're producing "Use of undefined constant" notices without them. Pick one type (single or double) and stick with it, otherwise you'll end up searching for both variations, should you need to find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenate with `.`

```
echo $eventid.$usernam.$hours."<br><br><br>";
```

I've done this countless times when going back and forth with `php` and `javascript`